# Hibernate Criteria API where clause in many to many relation

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, hibernate-criteria

I have relation many to many with extra fileds in linking table(mapping in xml files). Using criteria api how to add restrictions to name of product?

```
public class Recipe implements Serializable{

    private int id_re;

    private String name;

    private Set<ProductRecipe> listOfRecipe_Product = new HashSet<>(0);
}


public class ProductRecipe implements Serializable{

    private ProductRecipeMapping id;

    private float quantity;
}

public class ProductRecipeMapping implements Serializable{

    private Product product;

    private Recipe recipe;
}

public class Product implements Serializable{

    private int id_p;

    private String name;
}
```

Mapping:

```
<class entity-name="recipe" name="Recipe" table="recipe">
        <id name="id_re" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="id_re" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <set name="listOfRecipe_Product" table="recipe_product" lazy="false" fetch="select" cascade="all">
            <key>
                <column name="id_re" not-null="true" />
            </key>

            <one-to-many entity-name="productRecipe" />
        </set>
</class>

<class entity-name="productRecipe" name="ProductRecipe" table="recipe_product">
        <composite-id name="id" class="ProductRecipeMapping" >
            <key-many-to-one name="recipe" entity-name="recipe" column="id_re" />
            <key-many-to-one name="product" entity-name="product" column="id_p" />
        </composite-id>

        <property name="quantity" type="float" column="quantity" />

</class>    

<class entity-name="product" name="Product" table="product">

        <id name="id_p" type="java.lang.Integer" column="id_p">
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>

        <property name="name" column="name" type="java.lang.String" not-null="true" length="255"/>

</class>
```

E.G. I use criteria for get recipe with name test:

```
Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(Recipe.class);
cr.add(Restrictions.eq("name", "test"));
```

but I don't know to get all recipes with list name of products
something like cr.add(Restrictions.eq("product.name", "test")); (but not work)

I use 2 idea to resolve this problem but nothing work:

1) `Restrictions.eq("listOfRecipe_Product.id.product.name", "test")` 
but i get error `org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: listOfRecipe_Product.id.product.name of: recipe`

2)

```
cr.createCriteria("listOfRecipe_Product")
    .createCriteria("id")
    .createCriteria("product")
    .add(Restrictions.eq("name", "test"));
```

I get error `org.hibernate.QueryException: Criteria objects cannot be created directly on components. Create a criteria on owning entity and use a dotted property to access component property: listOfRecipe_Product.id`

Comment: Please be more specific: Do you want to write a query that will return alls Recipe that use a Product with a certain name? Also: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I added example in main description

Comment: I try use Restrictions.eq("listOfRecipe_Product.id.product.name", "test") but i get error org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: listOfRecipe_Product.id.product.name of: recipe

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create aliases in order to add constraints to mapped entities;

e.g.:

```java
Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(Recipe.class)
  .createAlias("listOfRecipe_Product", "listOfRecipe_Product")
  .createAlias("listOfRecipe_Product.id", "id")
  .createAlias("id.product", "product")
  .add(Restrictions.eq("product.name", "test"));
```

Comment: Maybe something is wrong in mapping? I get error org.hibernate.QueryException: Criteria objects cannot be created directly on components.  Create a criteria on owning entity and use a dotted property to access component property: listOfRecipe_Product.id

Comment: I've changed the example so it will represent your entity mappings, let me know if that works for you.

Comment: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: Recipe of: recipe
I dont know what is wrong all methods cant work properly, I get errors about access.... thx for your time and help

Comment: The first createCriteria was wrong, you should be querying the Recipe entity. I've updated the example

Comment: ans still org.hibernate.QueryException: Criteria objects cannot be created directly on components.  Create a criteria on owning entity and use a dotted property to access component property: listOfRecipe_Product.id